# Вывод картинки из файла на JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо на объект JPanel вывести картинку в свою очередь загружаемую из файла с помощью кнопки JButton.

```
public class FotoLable extends JFrame {
    Image image;
    public FotoLable() throws HeadlessException {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JLabel imageLabel=new JLabel();
        imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,400));
        imageLabel.setBounds(0,0,300,400);

        this.add(imageLabel,new GridBagConstraints(0,0,1,17,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
        JButton jButtonFileImage=new JButton("Выбрать фото");
        this.add(jButtonFileImage,new GridBagConstraints(GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE,0,1,1,1,1,GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST,GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(1,1,1,1),0,0));
        jButtonFileImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen=new JFileChooser();
                int ret=fileopen.showDialog(null,"Открыть файл");
                if (ret==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){File file=fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        image=ImageIO.read(file);
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Мой код не работает, подскажите почему?

Comment: Вы когда задаете вопрос, пожалуйста описывайте проблему подробнее, если не работает, то где? на какую строку жалуется? если просто не так как надо работает, опять же что у Вас происходит на экране, а как должно быть? по факту согласен с ezhov_da, все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять менеджер компоновки:

```
public class FotoLable extends JFrame {
    Image image;

    public FotoLable() throws HeadlessException {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
        JButton jButtonFileImage = new JButton("Выбрать фото");

        this.add(jButtonFileImage, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jButtonFileImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(file);
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FotoLable().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Только и здесь будет проблема если изображение больше окна. Вам необходимо само изображение в таком случае уменьшать.

Comment: Это фрагмент. Метод main у меня тоже присутствует. Однако при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит.

Comment: Если быть точнее, то форма создаётся, кнопка присутствует, файл выбирается, только изменений в imagePanel нет никаких.

Comment: Показывайте как вы работаете с классом FotoLable, так как у меня Ваш код рабочий, минус только в том, что картинка не полностью выводится из-за менеджера компоновки. Так же прикрепите тестовую картинку которая у Вас точно не отображается.

Comment: Да, действительно, это из за менеджера компоновки, подскажите как его изменить что бы картинка полностью влезла в существующий размер? Картинка - фото портрет.

Comment: UPD. Обновил ответ

Comment: А программно никак не сделать что бы изображение целиком вошло в окно? Оригинальное изображение точно будет больше.

Comment: Так я же и написал, вы программно должны уменьшить изображение пропорционально под нужные размеры

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать дальше, это уже выходит за тему вопроса.